# MVC Enviar datos de vista parcial con los de la vista contenedora al mismo controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

estoy haciendo un proyecto de prueba en MVC en el que tengo una vista y dentro de esta, cargo una vista parcial de forma condicional.

Tengo esta estructura de clases que utilizo como modelo:

```
public class DatosVehiculo
{
    public Vehiculo TipoVehiculo { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Vehiculo
{
    public string Marca { get; set; }
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
}

public class Moto : Vehiculo
{
    public int CentimetrosCubicos { get; set; }
}

public class Coche : Vehiculo
{
    public string Combustible { get; set; }
}
```

Tengo un controlador VehiculoController que tiene el siguiente código:

```
public class VehiculoController : Controller
{
    // GET: Vehiculo
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vehiculo = new DatosVehiculo();

        var rnd = new Random();
        if (rnd.Next(0, 2) == 1)
        {
            ViewBag.TipoVehiculo = "Moto";
            vehiculo.TipoVehiculo = new Moto() { CentimetrosCubicos = 200 };
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.TipoVehiculo = "Coche";
            vehiculo.TipoVehiculo = new Coche() { Marca = "BMW" };
        }

        return View(vehiculo);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(DatosVehiculo datosVehiculo)
    {
        if (datosVehiculo.TipoVehiculo is Moto)
        {
            GuardarMoto((Moto)datosVehiculo.TipoVehiculo);
        }
        else if (datosVehiculo.TipoVehiculo is Coche)
        {
            GuardarCoche((Coche)datosVehiculo.TipoVehiculo);
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException();

        return View();
    }

    private void GuardarMoto(Moto moto)
    {
        //...
    }

    private void GuardarCoche(Coche coche)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

En la vista del Vehículo tendría el siguiente código (en el que le paso a cada vista la propiedad "TipoVehiculo" que será de tipo Coche o Moto):

```
@model PruebaMVCLogin.Models.DatosVehiculo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.TipoVehiculo</h2>

<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Vehiculo", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Color, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Color, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                if (ViewBag.TipoVehiculo == "Moto")
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Vehiculo/_Moto.cshtml", Model.TipoVehiculo);
                }
                else
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Vehiculo/_Coche.cshtml", Model.TipoVehiculo);
                }

                <hr />

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y luego tendría las vistas parciales `_Coche.cshtml` y `_Moto.cshtml` que usarían los modelos `Coche` y `Moto` respectivamente (con sus textbox correspondientes).

El primer problema que me encuentro es que si declaro la clase `Vehiculo` como Abstract, me dice que no se puede instanciar una clase abstracta (aunque lo que yo pretendo es pasarle una clase derivada instanciada `Moto` o `Coche`).

Si la clase `Vehiculo` la dejo como pública, ese problema desaparece y al cargar la vista se ven perfectamente los datos que inicializo de las clases derivadas.
**Y aquí es donde llega el verdadero problema:**

Cuando le doy al botón de submit, los datos de la vista padre (la propiedad `Color`) llega al controlador sin problemas, pero la propiedad `TipoVehiculo` siempre llega a `null`.

¿Cómo puedo enviar al controlador los datos de la vista padre y los de la vista derivada en la propiedad `TipoVehiculo` con la instancia `Moto` o `Coche` según corresponda?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Y si declaras un input de tipo `hidden` para setear el tipo de vehiculo? No recuerdo mucho C# ni Razor pero creo que algo así podría servir.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando realizas el submit dentro del bloque `Html.BeginForm {}` no estas haciendo referencia al campo `m.TipoVehiculo`

Cuando realizas esto

```
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Vehiculo/_Moto.cshtml", Model.TipoVehiculo);
```

Solo estas obtenido el valor real del Modelo, sin embargo cuando se realiza el submit lo que realmente se envía al Controller es el `@model` y solo lo que se encuentra en el bloque `Html.BeginForm {}`

Es correcto lo que menciona @Dalamar, podrías settear el TipoVehiculo en un Hidden de la siguiente manera.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TipoVehiculo)
```

Con esto estaras recibiendo el modelo completo DatosVehiculo en el Controller.

Comment: Probando lo que dices del hidden no consigo que funcione. Sin embargo si en el `RenderPartial` de la vista padre pongo como parámetro `Model` y cambio en las partial los `@model` por `DatosVehiculo` sí se envían los datos, pero sólo los genéricos. No consigo que al controlador le llegue la propiedad `TipoVehiculo` como tipo `Coche` o `Moto` (que son clases derivadas de `Vehiculo`). Siempre llega del tipo `Vehiculo` que es el tipo base.